# If $A$ is infinite and $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $B$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My question reads:

> Prove: If $A$ is infinite and $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $B$ is infinite.

If finite then $A$ is either the empty set or $A$ is equivalent to $N_{k}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, where $N_{k}=\{1,2,\ldots ,k\}$.

Comment: If you think of infinite as "not finite", where finite means there's some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there's a surjection from $\{1, \ldots , n \}$ to your set, then you can show any surjection onto $B$ can be made into a surjection onto $A$.

Comment: I am not too sure where the surjection is coming from. Is this for equivalence?

Comment: You mean you don't see why a surjection onto a set can be made into a surjection onto its subset?

Comment: Suppose $f: X \to B$ is a surjection, that is for every $b \in B$, there's an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = b$. Now suppose $A \subseteq B$. Show there is a surjective map $g : X \to A$. Hint: Consider $f$, and for any $x \in X$ look if $f(x) \in A$ or $f(x) \in B \setminus A$. You should be able to see a way to fiddle with $f$ so as to make a new map.

Comment: I understand the definition of surjection you are saying but wouldn't it make more sense to contradict the definition of a finite set

Comment: That's what we're doing. One definition of finite set is that there's a surjection from $\{1, \ldots, n \}$ onto it for some $n$. So if $B$ is finite, then $A$ is finite; and by contraposition, if $A$ is not finite, then $B$ is not finite.

Comment: Hmm okay I think I get it. I'm looking back at my notes. I'm going to do it by contradiction. So in stead of saying for some k in N st.t. A equivalent to N_k it would be an for all statement?

Comment: Yes, infinitude is a "for all" statement in that we say, "For all $n$, for all maps $f: \{1, \ldots\ n\} \to S$, the map $f$ is not onto."

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is infinite, there is an injective function $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow A$. As $A\subseteq B$, it follows that there is an injective function $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow B$. So $B$ is infinite.

ALTERNATIVE PROOF:
Using [this definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteSet.html)

$A$ is infinite if there exists $C\subset A, C\ne A$ and a (bijective) 1:1 correspondence $f:C\rightarrow A$. Let $D=C\cup(B-A)$. Obviously $D\subset B, D\ne B$, and the function $g:D\rightarrow B$ defined as:

$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x)&\text{ if }x\in A\\
x&\text{ if }x\not\in A\\
\end{cases}
$$

is a bijection from $D$ to $B$, which means that $B$ is infinite.

Comment: For example [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_has_Countably_Infinite_Subset).

Comment: The proof depends a lot of what would you consider to be the definition of an "infinite set"

Comment: Well, on the top I have what I learned about a finite set. We haven't learn an infinite set yet, that's next lecture.

Comment: In this case, you could prove by induction like [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Finite_Set_is_Finite) that a subset of a finite set is finite. Then prove your statement by contradiction. Assuming that $B$ is finite, you have $A\subseteq B$ and it would follow $A$ is finite, contradiction.

Comment: In all honesty, I do not understand your answer. I was thinking we would have to disprove each part of the finite definition

Comment: So the one in the comments, which proves by induction that every subset of a finite set is finite, is still not good for you? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assumme that $B$ is a finite set, then there exists a bijection $f:B\rightarrow I_{n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now, since $A\subseteq B$, we have that $f|_A:A\rightarrow I_{n}$ it's an injection because it's the restriction of a bijection. This means that $|A|\le |I_{n}|=n$, so $A$ is finite, contradiction. Hence, $B$ must be an infinite set.

Comment: Yeah, my proof it's by contradiction. I'm using your definition of finite set (which is the standar one), just with different notation, i.e., $I_{n}=\{1,\ldots ,n\}$.

Comment: hmm, what do the | | mean?

Comment: $| X|$ means the cardinal of the set $ X$.